# Using <VirtualHost> over .htaccess for mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, virtualhost

I have a LAMP stack installed on Ubuntu 12.10 with three sites created under `/etc/apache2/sites-available`, all of which are working. My problem lies in wanting to use those files over `.htaccess` for appending the `.php` file extension from the URL. My file currently stands as such:

```
# The VGC
<VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerAdmin codyu@thevgc.net
            ServerName thevgc.net
            ServerAlias www.thevgc.net

            DocumentRoot /var/www/www
            <Directory />
                    Options FollowSymLinks
                    AllowOverride All
            </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/www/>
                Options Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews Includes
                RewriteEngine On
                RewriteBase /
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
                RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
                AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    </VirtualHost>
```

I'm almost certain I'm doing something wrong. All I know is that my `.htaccess` files refused to append the extension, or rather find the file that has the same name and load that file, so I wanted to go about this method.

Any suggestions? [Here is an example page from my site](http://www.thevgc.net/about).

Comment: I've created a file, `rewrite.conf`, inside of `/etc/apache2/mods-available` containing the following one line: `RewriteEngine On`
It didn't do anything.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Also, what is inside the .htaccess file?